# How do I run my native `pacman` against a mounted image?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I have read and followed [Is it possible to update, upgrade and install software before flashing an image?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/855/is-it-possible-to-update-upgrade-and-install-software-before-flashing-an-image). I managed to mount the official Arch image, synchronise the database and update the preinstalled packages. Unfortunately, it was rather slow. I think it was slow because `pacman` was being emulated, which seems a little excessive.

I did a little research and `man pacman` lists the following option

> -r, --root 
>   Specify an alternative installation root (default is /). This should not be used as a way to install software into /usr/local instead of /usr. This option is used if you want to install a package on a temporary mounted partition that is "owned" by another system.
>   **NOTE**: if database path or logfile are not specified on either the command line or in **pacman.conf**(5), their default location will be inside this root path.

Can we use exploit this option to install packages on a mounted image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes

It's not too hard. Make sure you have followed the instructions on [Is it possible to update, upgrade and install software before flashing an image?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/855/is-it-possible-to-update-upgrade-and-install-software-before-flashing-an-image) carefully and you have `qemu-user-static` installed correctly on the mounted system.

## pacman.conf

The `/etc/pacman.conf` file controls `pacman`, and normally, we wouldn't need to edit it. However, there is a problem with the supplied `pacman.conf` when used in this way. It includes the directive

```
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
```

Unfortunately, this picks up the mirror list from your host system, which probably won't mirror ARM packages. Copy `/etc/pacman.conf` from your mount to an appropriate directory and replace that line with

```
Server = http://mirror.archlinuxarm.org/arm/$repo
```

You can find my adapted `pacman.conf` at [github](https://github.com/alexchamberlain/pibake-1/blob/master/pacman/pacman.conf).

## Running `pacman`

You can now run `pacman`. Assuming your config file is in your `pwd`, run

```
sudo pacman -r <mount-point> --config pacman.conf -Syu
```

#### References

1. [Github project](https://github.com/alexchamberlain/pibake-1/tree/master/pacman), which is forked from @Jivings [Github project](https://github.com/Jivings/pibake).